# OutputLabel won't take font-size from css

Tags: css, primefaces

My primefaces outputlabel won't adjust to the font-size defined in my css. It adjusts to the font-weight tho. The label is bold but the text size is not changing.
Namespaces

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

CSS

```
.headLine {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25;
}
```

HTML

```
<p:outputLabel
  id="headline_id"
  value="Some headline"
  styleClass="headLine">
</p:outputLabel>
```

If i include the font-size directly in my html it works

Adding this to the outputLabel-Tag changes the size

```
style="font-size: 25"
```

I tried defining it with and without the unit "px". Also tried removing the font-weight attribute to see if it works if i only define the size. Didn't work either. I don't understand why it loads the font-weight attribute properly but the font-size is ignored when defined in the css.

Update: Using a `h:outputLabel` it works just fine with my css class. Only the primefaces component has this behavior

Comment: `p:outputLabel` means "in namespace `p`, create element `outputLabel`, which is XML, not HTML. Also `font-size` needs a unit like `px` or `pt`. And `styleClass` is not a HTML attribute, it's just `class`.

Comment: @Dai My p:outputLabel is generated as the html element <label id="..." class="..."></label> in the browser later on. As i also mentioned i tried it with and without the unit px. I would appreachiate less correction and more suggestion. For correction you can feel free to edit the post.

Comment: Your question wasn’t tagged with Primefaces, only HTML+CSS only. And when investigating HTML+CSS issues on StackOverflow it’s important to post the *rendered* HTML (or runtime DOM).

Comment: @Dai changed the tag now.

Answer (score 1):

You have an id headline but you are using class select  try

```
#headline_id {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 25px;
}

<p:outputLabel
   id="headline_id"
   value="Some headline"
   styleClass="headLine">
 </p:outputLabel>
```

or assign class

```
.headline_class {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}


<p:outputLabel
   class="headline_class"
   value="Some headline"
   styleClass="headLine">
</p:outputLabel>
```

Comment: My bad, the id in my actual code is not the same as the name of the class. I adjusted that in my original post. As i said my css seems to be loaded, since the outputlabel is actually bold and i only set this attribute in my css. It is just the font-size attribute which isn't effecting my label

Comment: @Basti have you tried giving font-size a unit? like 25px? Because it needs to have a unit

Comment: @Huangism as i said on the bottom of my post. Tried it with and without, so yes. I originally had it on px and changed to pt and nothing just to try it out if it changes anything. No difference

Comment: Asnwer  updated .. for upper/lower case correct match  (there was  headLine instead of headline).. px and class or id ..solutions

Answer (score 1):

Use the css !important rule

```
<p:outputLabel value="some stuff" style="font-size: 18px !important;"></p:outputLabel>
```